# best solution for make a ranged search on 2( or N) sorted set based on their score on Redis

Tags: sorting, optimization, redis

i have some index(sorted set) containing key name sorted with timestamp as score, these index are for searching purpose , for example one index apple and one index red , apple contain all key name referencing an apple and red all key referencing a red thing.

All this is sorted with the timestamp of the creation of the main key, so i want to do search with that.

For one fild it's not a problem , with pagination i do zrange on apple for example to get all apple within range of pagination sorted by date, but my problem are when i want to combine 2 field.

For example if want all red apple, i can do it sure, but i must use a zunionstore and zrange(too long) or get all of the 2 index to perform a filter based on date, and i search the fastest solution to do that.

thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

The approach you described - `ZUNIONSTORE` followed by a `ZRANGE` is the most efficient within Redis core. Alternatively, you could use [RediSearch](https://redisearch.io) for robuster indexing and searching abilities.